# How can I get top 5 from the point table? So those who have the most points

Tags: sql

```
$query = "  SELECT user_id, user_name, user_email, user_point, role_title 
                        FROM users 
                        INNER JOIN roles ON role_id = fk_roles_id
                        ORDER BY role_access DESC, user_name ASC LIMIT 5";
```

Comment: Well, you know the general idea.  Add the table that has points.

Comment: table set up already, but I want it to pick up only the top 5, that is, those with the most points

Comment: Try `order by user_point desc`.

Answer (score 0):

In Sql server you can do it like

```
$query = "SELECT TOP (5) COLUMN_NAME FROM TABLE_NAME ORDER BY COLUMN_NAME"
```